# Pushing the Result of Multiplication onto the Stack

Tags: assembly

I know this may be a simple matter, but I simply can not figure out how to push the result of an 16-bit multiplication onto the stack intact. As I understand it, the resultant of said multiplication is stored in the DX and AX register, so I just need the way to push these two values as one onto the stack.

Answer (score 6):

First push high word, then push low word.

```
push dx
push ax
```

This way they form the resultant dword at the address pointed to by the stackpointer.